# ScrollView changes suddenly its position

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I've a very strange problem with my scrollView.
First of all, this is my scrollView:[image]

...and in my viewDidLoad:

```
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,500);
```

The scrollView seems to work when I start the app. But when I scroll down to the bottom of the scrollView and click another tab in the tabBar while the scrollView is still at the bottom, and then go back to the tab (ViewController) with the scrollView, there is free space at the bottom added (which wasn't there before), but in return the top of the scrollView cuts off my content which is positioned at the top. *>>> The space which appears on the botton is left on the top of the scrollView*

This only happens, when you go to another tap while staying at the **bottom** of the scrollView.
I know this is very difficult to explain, but I hope you understand my problem and can help me.

I set the content the following way:

```
-viewController

   -View

        -Scroll View

            -buttons, images, etc.

   -tabBar item

   -navigationItem
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post more code, preferably where you load the content of the scrollview and where any possible resizing of the scrollview/content?

Comment: @ophychius I just did this in the storyboard.

Comment: try to set the frames in the viewWillappear method like scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,200);

Comment: @Tendulkar Sorry...same problem as before. [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630473/uitabbarcontroller-with-uiscrollview-scroll-offset-change-when-tab-switch)...this user seems to have the same problem

Comment: set the frame in the tabbar delegate called - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController method . put condition like this . If([viewController isEqual:v1])

Comment: @Tendulkar hm...also no success...maybe this is a problem of xcode

Comment: How are you setting the content in scrollview. Also are you changing content offset anyhow? You have AutoLayout enabled so it is of little use to simply set frame.

Comment: @Zen No, I've never did something with content offset. and yes, autolayout is enabled. I've updated may question

Comment: Is autolayout enabled ?

Comment: @DCMaxxx Yes...I use auto layout

Comment: I know the autolayout is enabled by first image only, thats why I mentioned setting up frames of views in that case is not of much use. Are you loading views in scrollview programmatically or just via IB?

Comment: @Zen I load the views just via IB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution now:

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```

...I now this solution is not 100% good, but for my problem its ok :)